# Provided service is undefined in function

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a service that is provided in app.module.ts and injected into an exported function (the function is also inside the app module). But when the code inside MSALInstanceFactory is ran, it says that the service is undefined.

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Configuration } from '../configuration/configuration';

@Injectable()
export class ConfigurationService {
  private configData: Configuration;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  async loadConfigurationData() : Promise<Configuration>{
    ...
  }
}
```

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    MsalModule,
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      ConfigurationService,
      {
          provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
          useFactory: (configService: ConfigurationService) =>
              () => configService.loadConfigurationData(),
          deps: [ConfigurationService],
          multi: true
      },
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: MsalInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }, 
    {
      provide: MSAL_INSTANCE,
      useFactory: MSALInstanceFactory
    },
    {
      provide: MSAL_GUARD_CONFIG,
      useFactory: MSALGuardConfigFactory
    },
    {
      provide: MSAL_INTERCEPTOR_CONFIG,
      useFactory: MSALInterceptorConfigFactory
    },
    ...
  ],
```

```
export function MSALInstanceFactory(configurationService: ConfigurationService): IPublicClientApplication {
  return new PublicClientApplication({
    auth: {
      clientId: configurationService.config.clientId
   });
```

I'm not sure what was problem is.

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide the dependency too:

```js
{
  provide: MSAL_INSTANCE,
  useFactory: MSALInstanceFactory,
  deps: [ConfigurationService]
},
```

Source: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers